# Highchart show and hide error

Tags: highcharts

Hi I want to hide the chart(highchart) onload, after loaded by click event I want to show the chart. But now after the click event it shows empty div and the chart is missing.

soon please.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebind the highchart initialization on click event.